# magento add product to cart and checkout from email id

Tags: cart, shopping-cart

i am working on php code that will programatically add product to cart and do checkout from email id

For example email id is abc@f.com

and product id is 1,2,4

Now i want php code to checkout product ids with using email .

i am using hint from below url 
http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-create-customer-and-order-in-magento-with-full-blown-one-page-checkout-process-under-the-hood/

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
    $product->load(1,2,3);
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    /* We want to add only the product/products for this user and do so programmatically, so lets clear cart before we start adding the products into it */
    $cart->truncate();
    $cart->save();
    $cart->getItems()->clear()->save();         
    try {
        /* Add product with custom oprion? =>  some-custom-option-id-here: value to be read from database or assigned manually, hardcoded? Just example*/
        //$cart->addProduct($product, array('options'=> array('some-custom-option-id-here' => 'Some value goes here');
        $cart->addProduct($product,1);
        $cart->save();              
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
    unset($product);




    // proceed order
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
    $checkout->initCheckout();
    $checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('register');
    $checkout->saveShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
    $checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'checkmo'));
    try {
        $checkout->saveOrder();
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        //echo $ex->getMessage();
    }           
    /* Clear the cart */
    $cart->truncate();
    $cart->save();
    $cart->getItems()->clear()->save();     
    /* Logout the customer you created */
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();
```